# PHP timer that uses a database as a reference point

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need to create a timer (hours, minutes, seconds) in PHP page that uses database as referent point. For example, many users have open page index.php and when one of then click Start, all other users will see that timer is executed.

I have this script for the count:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var c = 0;
    var t;
    var timer_is_on = 0;

    function timedCount() {
        document.getElementById('txt').value = c;
        c = c + 1;
        t = setTimeout("timedCount()", 1000);
    }

    function doTimer() {
        if (!timer_is_on) {
            timer_is_on = 1;
            timedCount();
        }
    }

    function stopCount() {
        clearTimeout(t);
        timer_is_on = 0;
    }
</script>
```

In my index.php I have jQuery that display data from database live:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#show').load('php/msa_pauza_refresh.php')
        }, 500);
    });
</script>
```

This script use data from Ajax file to show result in page. But the problem is when I start count script it will only count on the current page, on refresh, it will start again.

Comment: So you want a centralized counter? Regardless of who loads the page? Or does each user have their own counter? Your question title seems to hold the answer, maintain a database table and have the refresh return the incremented value.

Comment: I assume it's because you're var timer_is_on is set to 0 on page load. Could you perhaps output a PHP variable from your database there and once the timer is started change that column to 1? Then when timer is stopped change it back to a 0?

Comment: What happen if you manually call php/msa_pauza_refresh.php? Does it goes on counting or does it restart all the times? you have not published your backend php script, so I can't be sure that the problem is in your js code.

Comment: Yes i need centralized count, i will post result of calling Ajax file when o get back in office. But i think script in php is callinge every 3 second data from Ajax

Comment: Well, i check my output (php/msa_pauza_refresh.php) and it won't load data automatically. I guess that script refresh that page and get new data.

Comment: The problem is also if i have multiple rows and i wanted to start a timer on 3 rows at the same time, i think i need somehow update specific row until i click button STOP

Comment: Could you provide a database schema by any chance? Also, is there one super user that is allowed to start 'the' timer? Or can everyone start it? Are there multiple timers, all ran separately, or are we talking one timer only?